# Hibernate on Jboss7 OSGI (No EJB)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi

I use entity beans and some Stateless ejb that provide my `HomeLocal` and `HomeRemote` interface, where I inject `persistenceContext` and obtain `EntityManager`.

As new requirement (migration on Karaf) I have to get rid of all EJB.

My question is how can I replace this stateless ejb with simple DAO classes and inject or obtain Entity manager in these classes?

My JPA provider is hibernate.

I need some example, tutorials or any kind of help.

Comment: have a look at Apache Aries http://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Apache Aries project:

Amusing you will be using blueprint, declare your bean and define a service (assuming you want to use services)

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="jpaDemo" init-method="init" class="org.demo.osgi.datasource.jpa.JpaComponentImpl">
        <jpa:context unitname="demo" property="entityManager"/>
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
    </bean>

    <service ref="jpaDemo" interface="org.demo.osgi.datasource.jpa.JpaComponent"/>

</blueprint>
```

The `JpaComponent` can then use the injected `entityManager` (code in Scala, but i'm sure you'll get the idea)

```
trait JpaComponent {

}
class JpaComponentImpl extends JpaComponent {

  val logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[JpaComponent])

  @BeanProperty
  var entityManager : EntityManager = _

  def init = {
    logger.info(s"em=${entityManager}")
  }
}
```

Place a `persistence.xml` in your bundle (e.g, `META-INF/persistence.xml`). Sample below:

```
<persistence-unit name="demo" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/jbtravel)</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/airport.xml</mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

You will need the following features:

- jpa
- hibernate
- jndi
- transaction

And the following bundles

- `mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.0.1`
- `mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.api/1.0.1`
- `mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context/1.0.1`

Plus set the following OSGI meta-data

- Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
- Service-Component: *

See also https://github.com/rparree/osgi-demos/tree/master/datasource for the sample from above

Comment: it's look working on karaf. 
How can i make it work on JBoss ? Jboss do not inject persitence context from osgi bundle.

Comment: Notice now you are referring to "JBoss 7", but you also mentioned "karaf", These are two different platforms Are you perhaps not referring to JBoss Fuse? (for JBoss EAP 7 you would not have to "get rid" of ejb)